# Mixed Bootstrap form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Tried to create a bootstrap form which has two input fields horizontal & multiple select. Region 1 & Region 2 along with select should be next to input text field..
Can you please help, for me region 1 & 2 is coming below the input field.

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Bootstrap Form</h2>
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputId" placeholder="Enter Name"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAD" placeholder="IP address"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label class="col-sm-12" for="selBuy">Region 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <select class="form-control" id="selBuy" multiple="multiple" size="6">
            <option>California </option>
            <option>Atlanta</option>

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label class="col-sm-12" for="selCSP">Region 2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <select class="form-control" id="selCSP" multiple="multiple" size="6">
            <option>Google </option>
            <option>IBM</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

</form>
<hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have setup a fiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/1wpjxp1e/

Basically I have wrapped the input fields in a extra wrapping div

```
<div class="col-sm-12">...</div>
```

and the selectboxes too:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">...</div>
```

When I've done that you need to make sure that the intended size is kept so I changed the

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
```

To:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
```

Because it needs full size. Now you can see in the fiddle that both regions are next to the input fields.